# Are Stochastic Process Characterized by Their conditional Moments

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, moments

Suppose that $X_t$ is a real-valued stochastic process.  Then is $X_t$ characterized by it's conditional moments?  In the sence that, if $Y_t$ is another process, such that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^T\left(Y_t\right)^kdt|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_s^T\left(X_t\right)^kdt|\mathcal{F}_s\right],
$$
for all $0\leq s\leq T<\infty$, and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then are $X_t$ and $Y_t$, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. equal (assuming that the expressions are always well-defined)?

---

**Intuition:**

I expect it to be yes (in distribution at least).  Since this means that both have the same "conditional" Fourier Transforms, which I expect implies that they have the same Fourier Transform.  So they have the same transition density... Then using a representation theorem, I guess we can conclude they're the same.   But this is very hand wavy and probably wrong somehow...

Comment: What is $\mathcal F_s$ in this context? Is it somehow liked to the processes $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$?

Comment: Oh, its a right-continuous complete sub-filtration of the filtration they are both adapted to.

Comment: Aside from some qualifications regarding null sets and integrability, you can simply take $k=1$, divide by $T-s$, and send $T \to s$ to get $X_s=Y_s$.